# How is function main() inside a shared object (.so) taken care of by the linker?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

Suppose I have

- an object file (`source.o`) without function `main`.
- a shared object (`libmain.so`) with function `main`.

How will the linker take care of the entry point when both are linked dynamically to create binary `source.bin`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you have a dynamic linked program, there are several "entry points" involved. The first is in entry point of the dynamic linker itself, e.g. `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (on Linux/x86) or similar. The dynamic linker runs first, resolving all symbol names to their definitions (regardless of whether the definitions are in the main program or a library), then passes execution to the second entry point in the main program binary. This is not `main` but part of the "C runtime" (thus `crt.o` and similar names) that takes care of some pre-`main` stuff (like C++ ctors, setting up the pointer to the environment variables, and constructing the right arguments for `main`). This code ends with (the equivalent of) `exit(main(argc, argv));` which will use the relocated (by the dynamic linker) addresses of both `exit` and `main`.

Comment: I understand this, but when shared object have "main" function, and another object file also have "main" function, How to link them?

Answer (score 3):

`main()` is just like any other function however in hosted envrionment it is treated as the logical entry point of an c/c++ program. So there is nothing special with regards to linking of `main()` as an function.