# Pass function name from stdin and execute in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, stdin

As extra credit for a homework assignment I'm working on, we have to try and call `win()` by providing input to the executable of the below code (we can't change the code). We have to provide a number `n` and a value for `target`, which is then executed. I know what the value of `n` is. I'm not super well-versed in C, but I was looking through many other questions on here about using function pointers, and I thought passing in `&win` would work, but that just prints `Third challenge` an excessive amount of times and then seg faults. Can someone point me in the right direction, or to more resources so I could better understand how the function pointer is working in this program?

```
typedef void (*funcptr_t)();


int win()
{
    printf("Great Job\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    unsigned long long target;

    printf("Third challenge\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%llu", &target);
    if (n == 0xc0decafe) {
        funcptr_t funcptr = (funcptr_t)target;
        funcptr();
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708649/how-does-the-linker-find-the-main-function. The goal is to find out what address `win()` will be located at after the executable is loaded.

Comment: How are you getting what you think is the value of `&win`?

Comment: @jarmod that did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in advance, you could somehow work out what address the `win` function will have at runtime, then you can provide that address as the `target` input value. Then the code will be able to make a function pointer out of that value, which will correspond to the actual `win` function, and then invoke that function.

And the tool to help you get the address associated with a given function is typically the linker, or some kind of object/executable dump utility.

See [How does the linker find the main function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708649/how-does-the-linker-find-the-main-function) for an overview of the tools.